# Detect url the user is viewing in chrome/firefox/safari

Tags: macos, cocoa, security

How can you detect the url that I am browsing in chrome/safari/firefox via cocoa (desktop app)?

As a side but related note, are there any security restrictions when developing a desktop app that the user will be alerted and asked if they want to allow? e.g. if the app accesses their contact information etc.

**Looking for a cocoa based solution, not javascript.**

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as an extension, and because you would like  to target Chrome,  Safari, and Firefox, I'd use a cross-browser extension framework like Crossrider.

So go to crossrider.com, set up an account and create a new extension.  Then open the background.js file and paste in code like this:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.message.addListener({channel: "notifyPageUrl"}, function(msg) {
        //Do something, like send an xhr post somewhere 
            // notifying you of the pageUrl that the user visited.
        // The url is contained within msg.pageUrl      
    });

    var opts = { listen: true}; 
    // Note: When defining the callback function, the first parameter is an object that
    //       contains the page URL, and the second parameter contains the data passed
    //       to the context of the callback function.
    appAPI.webRequest.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(details, opaqueData) {
        // Where:
        //   * details.pageUrl is the URL of the tab requesting the page
        //   * opaqueData is the data passed to the context of the callback function
        if(opaqueData.listen){
            appAPI.message.toBackground({
                msg: details.pageUrl
            }, {channel: "notifyPageUrl"});
        }
    }, opts ); // opts is the opaque parameter that is passed to the callback function
});
```

Then install the extension!  In the example above, nothing is being done with the detected pageUrl that the user is visiting, but you can do whatever you like here - you could send a message to the user, you could restrict access utilizing the cancel or redirectTo return parameters, you could log it locally utilizing the crossrider appAPI.db API or you could send the notification elsewhere, cross-domain, to wherever you like utilizing an XHR request from the background directly.

Hope that helps!

And to answer the question on security issues desktop-side, just note that desktop applications will have the permissions of the user under which they run.  So if you are thinking of providing a desktop app that your users will run locally, say something that will detect urls they access by tapping into the network stream using something like winpcap on windows or libpcap on *nix varieties, then just be aware of that - and also that libpcap and friends would have to have access to a network card that can be placed in promiscuous mode in the first place, by the user in question.

the pcap / installed desktop app solutions are pretty invasive - most folks don't want  you listening in on literally everything and may actually violate some security policies depending on where your users work - their network administrators may not appreciate you "sniffing", whether that is the actual purpose or not.  Security guys can get real spooky so-to-speak on these kinds of topics.

The extension via Crossrider is probably the easiest and least intrusive way of accomplishing your goal if I understand the goal correctly.

One last note, you can get the current tab urls for all tabs using Crossrider's tabs API:

```
// retrieves the array of tabs
appAPI.tabs.getAllTabs(function(allTabInfo) {
    // Display the array
    for (var i=0; i<allTabInfo.length; i++) {
        console.log(
            'tabId: ' + allTabInfo[i].tabId +
            ' tabUrl: ' + allTabInfo[i].tabUrl
        );
    }
});
```

For the tab API, refer to: 
    http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.tabs

For the background navigation API: 
    http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.webRequest.onBeforeNavigate

And for the messaging: 
    http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message

And for the appAPI.db stuff:
    http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db

Comment: this has to be done via cocoa, not a javascript solution sorry.

Comment: Ah I see - thanks for the clarification, I hope you find a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html)?  You could have an app that launches, say, an Applescript which verifies if any of the well known browser is opened and ask them which documents (URL) they are viewing.

*Note:  It doesn't necessarily need to be an applescript; you can access the Scripting Bridge through cocoa.*

It would, however, require the browser to support it.  I know Safari supports it but ignore if the others do.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick note:

There are ways to do it via AppleScript, and you can easily wrap this code into NSAppleScript calls.

Here's [gist](https://gist.github.com/vitorgalvao/5392178#file-get_title_and_url-applescript) with AppleScript commands for Safari and Chrome. Firefox seems to not support AE.

Answer (score -1):

Well obviously this is what I had come across on google.

chrome.tabs.
getSelected
(null,
function
(tab) {
alert
(tab.url);
}) ;

Comment: Possible duplicate of <br/>

 stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-a-google-chrome-tab

Answer (score -2):

in pure javascript we can use

```
alert(document.URL);

alert(window.location.href)
```

function to get current url